# Devise allow user to change email with password and password confirmation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

In Devise, by default the user is required to add their current password when changing their email and has to have password confirmation for changing their password.

Is there a way where I can just have:

**Change Email**
`Email`
`Confirm button`

**Change Password**
`Current password`
`New password`
`Confirm button`

Do I have to edit the controller or can I just remove the form elements?

If I do have to edit the controller, which part do I change?

Comment: Rails security guide [suggests](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#e-mail) confirmation with password when changing the email.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think the wiki covers what you're looking for here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password

Comment: I was just looking at that but I didn't know which parts to remove.

Comment: Well I think that depends a bit on how you have things set up, but at some point, you're going to have to pass data into whatever controller you're looking at and update that data using Devise's `update_without_password` method.  Or, imo, you could skip all of Devise because it can be a pain sometimes and using something simpler like Sorcery which will give you more control over things like this.

Comment: Is it easy to remove Devise and use Sorcery instead in an application that's close to being finished? I've had my trouble with Devise over time and wondered if Sorcery is any better.